# How should I implement polyline mouse editing by knots using Python + GTK3

Tags: mouseevent, gtk3, hittest, pygobject

I googled around but didn't find a proper way to learn how I should implement mouse manipulation of lines in a `Gtk.DrawingArea` in Python.

The desired effect is similar to editing a Polyline/LineString in Google Maps

Specifically, I would like to:

- Hit-testing of points (circles) and line segments;
- Selection (picking), dragging and highlighting (mouseover);
- Creation and deletion of points;

I don't want a complete example (although one would be excelent), but instead just a way to START to develop this funcionality the Right Way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want hit-testing and interactivity, it is best to use a canvas library such as [GooCanvas](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/stable/index.html).

Comment: That seems interesting... Do you where I could find the python bindings documentation (installation and running examples)?

Comment: There's no proper story for generating Python bindings documentation for GObject introspection modules. The best you can do is read the C API and translate it mentally to Python (with help from `dir(GooCanvas)` and `/usr/share/gir-1.0/GooCanvas*.gir`).